# List view time limit exceeded error

Tags: list-view, timeout

When I try to load an account list view it is giving me a time exceeded error. The list view need to return only 50 records, I tried it out using SOQL in dev console. So I don' think it is an data volume issue. Moreover other list views on account are working fine(and they return about 5 million records, courtesy:data loader). The error I am getting is

> "Time limit exceeded : Your request exceeded the time limit for
>   processing. "

Please help me regarding how to fix this. Should I contact salesforce help?

Comment: Did you try generating a report with the same criteria as in this list view?

Comment: I don't have access to generate reports yet. Am trying to get an admin do that.